# Check out not required but created files are in check out status

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

Today, for the first time, I watched an anomaly behaviour in all my SPO sites (all in classic experience).

I have Document Libraries where it's not required documents to be checked out, until yesterday when I created new documents they were in "check in" status but today they are created in "checked out" status.

To be exact, the first document I create in a Document Library is in "check in" status, all the further documents in "check out" status: what happened? How can I create every time documents in "check in" status?

**Update:**
I have done some tests but I have to give you some more information.

I have a custom Content Type for Document Set and one for files present in the Document Set. Two properties of the Document Set are Shared Columns with the Content Type of the files: if I set these properties as hidden I can create a file in "check in" status. My problem is I need these properties are visible.

Comment: It would also be usefull to know if anyone else has observed the same strange beahviour.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Library Settings -> Version Settings -> Require Check Out set to Yes:

[image]

The set above will make file check out after uploading files in library.

Comment: It has been the first thing I've done: but it's set to "No".

Comment: Did this issue happen for all the library or a specific one ?

Comment: It happens in 4 different Document Libraries in the same Site Collection. Besides of it I have 3 different Site Collections with the same Document Libraries: untill last week it never happened now it happens in every Document Library, in every Site Collection.

Comment: Is there any changes recently in your side ? If creating the new library, the issue will also happen ?

Comment: None: I have a Site Collection that I haven't touch since December and it behaves as the other.
I've updated the post with some information may be usefull (I hope).

Comment: Maybe the custom content type have some required property ? So the file will be checked out status when uploading ?

Comment: When I open the properties all required fields are correctly filled, the 2 shared columns too (inherited from the Document Set). The weirdest thing is that if I set these 2 properties as hidden, new files are creted in "check in status".

Comment: Maybe a delay, some asynchronous call by SPO?

Comment: As I know, OOTB library won't have asynchronous call in backend, only like flow/remote event receiver will trigger after file created. Anyway, currently, this issue actually caused by the document set properties based on the discussion.